# Zend Studio exclude Files from commit

Tags: svn, external, zend-studio, subversive

Does anybody know how to exclude files from commit in Zend Studio? I found this option in Netbeans very useful and would like to use it here, too.

I have an external in my project I had to make changes to, but don't want them committed.

Comment: seems that this is not possible with Zend Studio or any Eclipse Plugin for SVN

Answer (score 1):

You can enable this option on Zend Studio.
Navigate to SVN Preferences (Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN), and uncheck the last option of first set "Show selected resources in resource changes pane. Otherwise resources are shown in table".

Comment: last option is already unchecked, but file keeps showing up in commit

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the folder/file: go to Team -> Add to svn:ignore...

That's with version 9.

Comment: Oh, I thought it's a file only you had on your localhost. What about just unticking the file then when you commit? If there's lots of files, etc: that is why branches were created, and then you should look at that. Also, you can right-click on the folders where the file is not a child of, then it's also not in the list; only the files in and recursive in the directory you want to commit. Then you can commit 'around' it without having to untick :p

Comment: "What about just unticking the file then when you commit?" that's what I'm doing right now. But you have to do it every time you commit and the project always shows one file changed. In Netbeans there's an option to exclude a file from commit, so it's greyed out and the project doesn't look like something is not committed. That's what I was searching for...